# Wordpress - how can I fetch more posts via AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

To begin with, I think this is a longshot but hopefully there is someone out there that can help.

To explain the current situation, at the moment I have a custom plugin that grabs various bits of information about a user and their 4 most recent posts.

I am also using the WPBook plugin (so this is on facebook and just just a typical wordpress site)

Ok, so here is my code that is grabbing the 4 most recent posts for a user:

```
// The Query
query_posts('posts_per_page=4&author='.$blogger_id);

// set $more to 0 in order to only get the first part of the post
global $more;
$more = 0;

// the Loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
    <div class="oe-grid-box">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" <?php the_title()?></a>
        <div class="oe-grid-box-content">
            <?php echo the_content( '...' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="oe-grid-pic">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
                <span class="<?php echo strtolower($category); ?>"></span>
            </a>
            <?php echo $image; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>


<div id="load-more">Load More</div>
```

I tried following this tutorial but instead of a separate plugin, placing the code in my existing plugin but now my page won't load:

http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/

Ideally, want I want to is when the load more button is clicked, fetch 4 more posts and show them.

If anybody could help I'd really appreciate it.

**UPDATE**

Ok,

so far I've added in my jQuery to call the php file which should hopefully return posts but it doesn't work.

I am thinking that it's because it doesn't know what the WordPress functions are?

If I put a simple `echo` in my load more script, the jQuery success function shows an alert to say it worked, but if I start doing WordPress stuff I get an internal server error, this is the code in the load-more.php file:

```
// load wordpress into template
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require($path .'/wp-load.php');


$blogger_id = $_GET['id'];
$firstname  = $_GET['firstname'];
$surname    = $_GET['surname'];
$posts      = $_GET['posts'] + 4;
$category   = $_GET['category'];
$image      = $_GET['image'];

// The Query
query_posts('paged='.get_query_var('paged').'&posts_per_page=' . $posts . '&author='.$blogger_id);

// set $more to 0 in order to only get the first part of the post
global $more;
$more = 0;

// then the same loop as in my page that is making the ajax call.
```

Comment: Hmm, I would use jQuery and this post to pull the proper posts: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

Comment: When you say tha the page won't load, what do you mean? Does it display some error messages?

Comment: @VladimirKadalashvili - yes, the page breaks, no error messages are shown though but that would probably be because I haven't turned error reporting on.

Comment: @Jeremy thanks, I will give it a try and see what happens!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a lot of effort, I found the answer, here is a solution for those stuck in the same position.

This goes in your plugin page where you are getting posts for a user etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        posts = 8;
        author_posts = parseInt(<?php echo $author_posts; ?>);

        $("#link_selector").click(function() {

            // alert('posts - ' + posts + 'author posts - ' + author_posts);


            if ((posts - author_posts) > 3) {
                $("#link_selector").text('No more posts!');
            }
            else {

                var category        = '<?php echo strtolower($category); ?>';
                var id              = '<?php echo $blogger_id; ?>';
                var firstname       = '<?php echo $firstname; ?>';
                var surname         = '<?php echo $surname; ?>';


                // alert(posts + category + id + firstname + surname);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'loadMore', id: id, firstname: firstname, surname: surname, posts: posts, category: category}),
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#ajax_results_container').hide().fadeIn('slow').html(data);
                        posts = posts + 4;

                        if ((posts - author_posts) > 3) {
                            $("#link_selector").text('No more posts!');
                        }

                    }
                });
            }

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Then in your theme's functions.php, put your function to do your ajax request:

```
function loadMore() {

    $blogger_id = $_GET['id'];
    // get your $_GET variables sorted out

    // setup your query to get what you want
    query_posts('posts_per_page=' . $posts . '&author='.$blogger_id);

    // initialsise your output
    $output = '';

    // the Loop
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        // define the structure of your posts markup

    endwhile;

    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();

    die($output);

}
```

Then, just after the closing of your function, put in the action hooks

```
add_action('wp_ajax_loadMore', 'loadMore');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadMore', 'loadMore'); // not really needed
```

That's it!

Comment: I understand, that it's been a long time..) but, please, say what should be in this php file? `url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"` And how should I "define the structure of your posts markup"? Just insert html without anything? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @mankutila, it's been a while so I'm struggling to remember. I'm sure `loadMore()` goes in `functions.php` (from your theme) as stated in the question, `/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` must use that somehow, as, if you edited a WordPress core file, you'd lose all your changes every time you updated. The markup mentioned is just your html, so build that up via string concatenation, e.g. in the loop: `$output += 'your html here';`

Comment: It means I should instead of `// define the structure of your posts markup` insert `$output= '<div class="inserted_content"></div>'? Thanks

Comment: @mankutila yes, exactly. Things might have changed since WordPress has had a few versions released between then and now but hopefully it should still work, I haven't done any WP stuff since so I'm not in a position to know if things are still the same or not.