# How to make a specific loop for this function that gets the posts?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I am doing some WordPress theming. I have a #novelsslider div. Inside  of #novels, I used this code to get the latest three posts in the "novels" category, inside of the html divs, I used some php functions to get the latest 3 posts and load the html 3 times floated to the left to build a slider:

```
<!-- slider -->       
<div id="novelsslider" class="slider">

<? $novels = get_option('of_novels') ?>
<?php query_posts('category_name=$novels&posts_per_page=3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="sliderunit">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <div class="novelsslidertitle">
            <div class="arrow-left"></div>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <img class="cross" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/cross.png"/>
                </a>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>        
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endwhile;?>

        <div id="novelsslidebars">
            <input type="submit" value="" class="slidebars" id="novelsslidebtnleft">
            <input type="submit" value="" class="slidebars" id="novelsslidebtnmiddle">
            <input type="submit" value="" class="slidebars" id="novelsslidebtnright">
        </div>

    </div> 
<!-- End novelsslider -->
```

ow I have some arrows.. I want them when clicked to get a set of previous 3 posts and load them, how can I do such a loop?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can adopt any of these methods :

1- If your posts are not in large number then you can preload them and store in some container which is hidden by default and will appear when you click the next / previous button, like a content slider, but this is a bad approach and not recommended.

2- Use AJAX to load the rest of the posts, this is a good method and will be purely dynamic. Look on the following links to have the idea:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-loopy-ajax-powered-loops-with-jquery-and-wordpress/

[Wordpress - how can I fetch more posts via AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887760/wordpress-how-can-i-fetch-more-posts-via-ajax)